# Fastest way to check if a list is present in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list

```
a=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

What is the fastest way to check if any list in `a` is present in another list of lists `b`, where

```
b=[[5, 9, 25, 31, 33, 36],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[10, 13, 22, 24, 33, 44]]
```

If any list in a is present in b, I would like to remove it. I'm currently using this code:

```
for each in a:
    for item in b:
        if set(each).issubset(item)
            a.remove(each)
```

This works but is quite slow when working with large lists so was wondering if there's a better way. The above code gives me the following result:

```
print(a)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

I am not worried about order, for example if a list in `a`is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` I want it to be removed if there exist a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` or `[3,4,1,6,2,5]` etc in list `b`.

Comment: What if `a` is `[[1, 1, 2, 3]]` and `b` is `[[7, 3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6]]`?

Comment: @bipll That is acceptable as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `list comprehension` with `set`.

**Ex:**

```
a=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]]  
b=[[5, 9, 25, 31, 33, 36],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[10, 13, 22, 24, 33, 44]]

setA = set(map(tuple, a))
setB = set(map(tuple, b))

print([i for i in setA if i not in setB])
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this definitely worked faster. Tested on a list `a` with 1 million items against a list `b` with 1646, and it only took 1.9 sec. My solution took forever.

Comment: I believe this doesn't work for lists in different orders

Answer (score 1):

A functional solution is possible using `set.difference`:

```
res = set(map(tuple, a)).difference(set(map(tuple, b)))

[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
```

**Explanation**

1. Since `list` is not a hashable type, we convert sublists to type `tuple`, which are immutable and hashable, e.g. `set(map(tuple, a))`.
2. Then use `set.difference` to take the difference between the 2 resulting sets.

Comment: Cheers for the solution it was definitely more faster than mine, took about 5 sec when tested on a list `a` with 1 million items against a list `b` with 1646 but Rakesh's example proved way faster.

Comment: Can you recheck timing now? I've updated to remove `tuple` -> `list` conversion. It seems this time-consuming part isn't necessary for your use case.

Comment: Sure yeh it definitely improved now takes on average about 2.2sec, way better.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about elements order and frequencies, i.e. treat lists as unordered sets, then probably your solution is almost the correct one (removing an element while iterating the same list is probably not the best idea) with two serious suboptimalities.

First, you currently convert each b's element into a set *once per each* element of a. I wonder if Python compiler can optimize the repeated work out, at least you could try to do it on your own.

Next, you don't need to remove elements incorrectly and quadratically to simply filter them out.

```
faster_b = [frozenset(x) for x in b]

def not_in_b(list):
    l = frozenset(list)
    for x in faster_b:
        if l <= x: return False
    return True

print(list(filter(not_in_b, a)))
```

This one is probably faster.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, May 11 2018, 04:00:52) 
[GCC 8.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
>>> b=[[5, 9, 25, 31, 33, 36],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[10, 13, 22, 24, 33, 44]]
>>> faster_b = [frozenset(x) for x in b]
>>> 
>>> def not_in_b(list):
...     l = frozenset(list)
...     for x in faster_b:
...         if l <= x: return False
...     return True
... 
>>> print(list(filter(not_in_b, a)))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
>>> a=[[1, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> b=[[7, 3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> faster_b = [frozenset(x) for x in b]
>>> print(list(filter(not_in_b, a)))
[]
>>> a=[[1, 1, 2, 3], [42, 5, 6]]
>>> print(list(filter(not_in_b, a)))
[[42, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: I got an error `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable` for the line `print(list(filter(a, not_in_b)))`

Comment: Ah, apparently, it's the argument order to `filter`, see my edit.

Comment: Had to stop the script for your edited code as it went over 2min and python froze.

Comment: @West You've probably copied something wrong. I have edited my post with brief demonstration how it works.